# Maven can't find the Java Discord API dependency

Tags: java, maven, discord-jda

I've tried for a while to figure out the problem with this project, but I just can't figure it out. I've setup a project in IntelliJ, set it to work with Maven, but as I'm writing the pom.xml it claims that the dependency I'm using doesn't exist.

Well, I know for a fact that the dependency code is correct, as both the GitHub and the Maven website share the same IDs and version, I can find it in [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dv8tion/JDA/5.0.0-alpha.9), the [API's GitHub](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/blob/master/README.md) and even the [API's Release Note](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/releases/tag/v5.0.0-alpha.9).

This is my pom.xml for anyone wondering (I've anonymized my project info)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>MyGroupID</groupId>
   <artifactId>ArtifactID</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>MyProjectName</name>
   <description>ShortProjectDescription</description>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
         <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
         <version>5.0.0-alpha.9</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Run maven from the command-line, in debug mode: `mvn -X install` and check the error you receive.

Comment: I tried it, and it downloads all the dependencies without any error.

Comment: @Lesiak How do I do that? I've only recently started using Maven (through IntelliJ's integration with it) and I have no proper knowledge of how to use it

Comment: @AntonioPetricca IntelliJ is highlighting the syntax and pointing out "Dependency 'net.dv8tion:JDA:5.0.0-alpha.9' not found "

Comment: Open the Maven window and Reload project.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha That solved it! Sorry for my lack of Maven proficiency. May I know what could be the cause that got fixed with a reload of the project?

Comment: I think you have to have auto-import configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just typed in the dependency in IntelliJ, it's yet to be downloaded and put into the external libraries folder for your project to use.

You need to reload the maven project for IntelliJ to download the dependency and then the error will go away.

Right-click on the pom file and select Maven, then select reload project:
[image: Intellij_maven_reload_project]

### EDIT:

I saw in the above comments that you wanted to enable auto-import. If you are on version v2020.1 or above, auto-import functionality has been removed. I would recommend reading [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/01/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap/#maven_and_gradle_importing_updates).

Also, you can use keyboard shortcuts for reloading maven:

Windows/Linux - Ctrl+Shift+O

Mac - Command + Shift + I

Comment: Yes, that auto-import _was_ always really annoying. Glad it was removed :)

Comment: Thanks! That solves my issue, so for future reference, everytime I use a new dependency from Maven I have to reload the project for IntelliJ to know that it exists right? Does that mean IntelliJ just recognizes dependencies of which I have a local copy of? Or have I completely misunderstood?

Comment: When intellij builds your project or reloads the project it checks the pom file and sees if the dependency mentioned is present in external libraries. If not it downloads it or grabs it from your local .m2 folder if present.